# How to add a filter to Mixpanel (like in Google analytics)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-analytics, mixpanel

I want to filter my home ip from mixpanel.  In Google Analytics, I can do this by adding a filter to my profile.  Is there something similar in mixpanel or a work around to achieve the same result? My app is built in Rails 3, hosted on heroku.  Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Spoke to their support and they'd suggested that I block api.mixpanel.com in my host file, which works.

Comment: My router has a method for clocking specific websites. I did this, now I don't get any views from my internal network, which is perfect!

Comment: sudo bash -c 'echo "api.mixpanel.com localhost" >> /etc/hosts'

Answer (score 1):

One problem with the above solution is that it is hard edit the hosts file on mobile devices.

Here is a different workaround:

- Create a "secret" HTML file called x.html (or whatever) that sets a special cookie, and upload it to your site.

  ```
  <html>
  <head>
      <title>mixpanel cookie</title>

      <script type="text/javascript">
          document.cookie = "analytics-ignore=true; max-age=31536000; path=/";
      </script>
  </head>
  <body>
      setting cookie.
  </body>
  ```
- in your site/app, check for this cookie before running the mixpanel initiation script.

  if( document.cookie.indexOf('analytics-ignore') === -1 ) {
  //...mixpanel code...
  }
- Note that you may want to check for the existence of `mixpanel` variable before calling its methods (`mixpanel.track`).

Simply visit the `x.html` page once (well, once per year, per browser, and after clearing your cookies, etc..)

Answer (score 1):

Blocking the Mixpanel API by running `sudo bash -c 'echo "127.0.0.1 api.mixpanel.com" >> /etc/hosts'` worked for me on OS X. This also works with Segment.io.